# C - Child Process Not Executing

Tags: c, multithreading, unix, multitasking

[SOLVED]
So for this practice exercise I was assigned we are practicing process control. I'm simply wondering why it seems that my child process will never execute (when child_pid == 0). Any help on this issue would be greatly appreciated!
Also, safe_fork() is a function our instructor wrote in order to avoid students opening too many processes.

```
#include "safe-fork.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>

int main(void) {

  pid_t child_pid;
  int pipefd[2];
  int pipe_result;
  int count;

  pipe_result = pipe(pipefd);

  if (pipe_result == -1) {
    perror("pipe failure");
    exit(1);
  }

  child_pid = safe_fork();

  /*Parent Process*/
  if (child_pid > 0) {
    dup2(pipefd[0], STDIN_FILENO);
    scanf("%d", &count);

    if (count > 200) {
      printf("Long enough!\n");
      exit(0);
    }
    else {
      printf("Too short!\n");
      exit(1);
    }

  }
  /* Child Process */
  else {
    dup2(pipefd[1], STDOUT_FILENO);
    execl("/usr/bin/wc", "-w");
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: when calling any of the  `scanf()` family of functions, always check the returned value (not the parameter values) to assure the operation was successful.  when calling any of the `exec()` family of functions, they only return if an error occurred, so follow the call with: `perror( "exec?? failed"); exit(1);`

Comment: The parent process should call `waitpid( child_pid, NULL ); before returning.  In the current scenario, the child will never return because no file/input is passed to the `wc` function so it will sit forever, looking at stdin, for input.  Suggest adding another parameter that is the name of a file those words are to be counted.  Note: parameters lists to `execl()` should end with a NULL parameter.  Note: exiting the parent process makes the child process (if it has not already exited, which in this scenario it has not exited) into a `zombie` process, requiring a reboot to eliminate.

Comment: When calling `fork()`, there are three return value, not just two,  (I.E. -1 on error)  The code needs to properly handle the -1 return value.

Comment: the call to `execl()` function has the syntax: `int execl(const char *path, const char *arg, ...
                       /* (char  *) NULL */);` so this line: `execl("/usr/bin/wc", "-w");` should be more like: `execl("/usr/bin/wc", "-w", file.txt, (char *) NULL );`

Comment: Suggest indent each level 4 spaces as that will be visible even with variable width fonts

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a suggestion, check for child_pid == 0 explicitly cause it could also be the case that your safe_fork() function failed, also check for those errors i.e child_pid < 0.
Add debug printf statements to check control flow if you already haven't and finally check if the execl call failed.

Also please have a look at this [tutorial](http://tldp.org/LDP/lpg/node11.html) for creating pipes in C and using them to communicate between a parent and a child process. As I feel there are some issues with how you are handling those file descriptors. A possible reason that you can't see any output is that wc might still waiting for some input.

And another thing you might need to wait for the child process to complete/do something useful or actually be run before checking for its output. Check the other issues first before you worry about this.

Hope this Helps :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, But no. First you should carefully understand the meaning of fork().
**fork():** creates a child process and it returns into **TWO PROCESSES, with different return value in each.**  In parent, it always returns the number that OS has assigned for the newly created child's process id. At the same it returns in newly created child also, as child process will start executing the code copied from parent just after the fork() statement. In child fork always returns zero. So normally after a fork() system call, people check for returned value by fork to differentiate child process and parent process.

particularly in this case after a fork(), there will be two processes with same code and same program states(except both will have different value assigned in child_pid variable). In parent its a non zero value (which is corresponding to child's pid) and in child, its the value zero as the fork returns zero in child.
Now both processes will execute

```
if (child_pid > 0)
```

which is true only for parent so parent process will flow into 'if block' and is false for child so it will directly jump to else part and will execute the else block.

**What if child_process id is zero?**
OS will always assign a non zero value for a child so that fork() will work. And if you have somehow got child process id as zero then parent will fail to enter in 'if block' and will execute else block which is the same as child.